# Codeigniter 3: executeing a series of functions only if the user is loggedin gives a "Too Many Redirects" error

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I am working on a *Register and Login* application with CodeIgniter 3 and Twitter Bootstrap.

The application has 2 tables: *users* and *customers*. Once logged in the *users* can add their *customers*.

An HTML table containing customers must show up at `example.com/home` but *only if the user is logged in*.  To achieve this, I have written:

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {      
    public function index() {
        if ($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')==FALSE) {
            redirect('Signin/signin');
        } else {
            $this->customers(); 
        }
    }
    public function customers(){
        // More code here
    }
}
```

This works fine, but there are other operations - adding, editing, deleting uses - that I also want to be possible only for logged in users. So I added code to the above snippet and got:

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {      
    public function index() {
        if ($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')==FALSE) {
            redirect('Signin/signin');
        } else {
            $this->customers();
            $this->create();
            $this->save();
            $this->edit($customer_id);
            $this->update($customer_id);
            $this->delete($customer_id);
        }
    }        
    public function customers(){
        // More code here
    }
    public function edit($customer_id){
        // More code here
    }
    /* The rest of
    the functions
    here */
}
```

The result of this is a "Too Many Redirects" error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the user should be allowed to perform one operation at a time.

First, when the user is logged_in, redirect him to the customer list.

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {

     public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        //instead of checking the user whether he is logged in, 
           //in every function, check it in the constructor
        if (!$this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')) {
           redirect('Signin/signin');
        }
     }        

     //function to show customer lists
     public function index() {
        //query all the customers added by the user and pass it to view
        $this->load->view('customer_list_view',$data);
     }

     If the user wants to add a customer, add a function to show the form
    //customer add/edit form view
    public function add_customer(){
        //show form view
        $this->load->view('customer_add_view');
    }

    //save/update customer
    public function save_customer($userid = NULL){
        //save or update based the availability of the user in the database. For a new user, userid will be null.
    }

    //delete customer
    public function delete_customer($userid){
       //delete the customer here
    }
}
```

Comment: I have improved my answer. Please check it out.